# python3 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

Tags: python-3.x

My code is runnning in respberry pi 3 and I have error messages while trying to open it in terminal. What's wrong with my code, or where I made mistakes?
And I tried to rename it , but it does not work

> import work.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2218, in
>
> _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**path**'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< stdin>", line 1, in < module>
>
> ImportError: No module named 'work.py'; 'work' is not a package